# How to implement @SqlCall to call the stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have to use the @SqlCall to call the stored procedure [Using Oracle DB]. Kindly anyone help me on how to implement it.

I have tried implementing it in the below way, but could not succeed. Input and out puts are both array types.

```
public interface OrderDao {
  @SqlCall("{call prepare_order_from_cart(:cartId, :orderId, :orderTotal)}")
  @OutParameter(name = "orderId",    sqlType = java.sql.Types.BIGINT)
  @OutParameter(name = "orderTotal", sqlType = java.sql.Types.DECIMAL)
  OutParameters prepareOrderFromCart(@Bind("cartId") long cartId);
}
OutParameters outParams = orderDao.prepareOrderFromCart(cartId);
```

Comment: please tag the database that you are using

Comment: Data base is Oracle